# add div after image in post

Tags: posts, css

I want to give my photos a special style
such as this link
"[CSS3 Hover Effects](http://www.alessioatzeni.com/wp-content/tutorials/html-css/CSS3-Hover-Effects/index_4.html)"
For this, I must add a div after any image link in any post
What should i do For this style ?
I am using Hueman Theme And local host .
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little light on detail of what you want to happen precisely.

In general anything in WordPress *content* is usually treated as such. It's not very friendly to being mixed with code, although many solutions try (often with poor results).

The basic approach would be to use `the_content` filter to process post content on display and insert modifications as necessary.

Other options I can think of would be inserting changes when post is save or customizing markup of image being inserted into content (`image_send_to_editor` filter).

Comment: Thanks
image_send_to_editor filter was suggested to me by other friends
but i dont know to use this filter
is a tutorial for this ?